# FX Console plugin for After Effects not working on M1 Macs

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-scripting

The (very useful) VideoCopilot plugin [FX Console](https://www.videocopilot.net/tutorials/fx_console_plugin/?vc=true) doesn't appear to work with M1 Macs with After Effects CC 2022.  Is there any workaround?

When you open the plugin in After Effects, this error appears as the window tries to draw:

[image: screengrab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems they’ve just announced updated M1 versions of most of their plugins, including FX console:

https://www.videocopilot.net/products/m1/

Comment: You are my hero. This answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the Intel version of AE via the CC App Panel as a workaround.

Answer (score -1):

AEscripts - [QuickMenu](https://aescripts.com/quick-menu/). Decent replacement. Does a bit more. Can apply stuff to multiple layers etc. I swapped over to it today and it works great as I' not sure FX Console would ever get updated....

Comment: I've bought it - it feels slower to respond than FX Console... (Might be because I'm doing stuff in the background maybe)

Answer (score -1):

Run After affect Intel version in Creative Cloud App. [image]
Creative Cloud App > Apps > All apps > After effect > Button (...) > Open (Intel)
Done!